# CBT Export BigTable Data

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable, bigtable, cbt

I am looking for a way to export data from CBT instance using `cbt` commands.

I could see it working from GUI using [following steps](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/import-export).

However, I am looking to do it from Terminal. Is there a way I can do that?

P.S. I already tried this:

```
curl -f -O http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/cloud/bigtable/bigtable-beam-import/1.1.2/bigtable-beam-import-1.1.2-shaded.jar ...
```

Not working for me.

Comment: What format are you looking to export the data in? The page you linked has a few different format options you can export data with and that is kinda a big factor for how you want to export. cbt allows you to read data, so you could just write a bash script using the read command and log that to a file

Comment: @BillyJacobson what I am looking for is the `cbt export` or something like command. I will create a script for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki as it's based on @BillyJacobson's comment.

The difference between exporting data using the GUI and cbt commands is that the GUI allows you to export data into specific formats while the cbt commands allow you to just read data.

So if you want to export data through cbt commands you are going to have to create a bash script that uses the read command and log that to a file.

The command you will have to use, as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/cbt-reference#read_rows) is the following:

```
cbt read <table-id> [start=<row-key>] [end=<row-key>] [prefix=<row-key-prefix>] [regex=<regex>] [columns=<family>:<qualifier>,...] [count=<n>] [cells-per-column=<n>] [app-profile=<app-profile-id>]
```

Where the value are represented by:

```
start=<row-key>                     Start reading at this row
end=<row-row>                       Stop reading before this row
prefix=<row-key-prefix>             Read rows with this prefix
regex=<regex>                       Read rows with keys matching this regex
columns=<family>:<qualifier>,...    Read only these columns, comma-separated
count=<n>                           Read only this many rows
cells-per-column=<n>                Read only this many cells per column
app-profile=<app-profile-id>        The app profile ID to use for the request
```

Comment: What I am looking for is the command. Format and everything can be taken care. That's my initial question is

Comment: Ok, got it, I edited the answer with the command that is suppose to be used.